# Setting up a Server running and Wifi Network

Tags: c, sockets, wireless

On a computer system I setup the Server running

```
int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
unsigned int clilen;
char buffer[256];
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

int n;

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);



bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

portno=3000;
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

char *srvr_addr=NULL;
srvr_addr="127.0.0.12";
inet_addr(srvr_addr);

serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr(srvr_addr);


serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

listen(sockfd,5);

while (1)
{

clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

bzero(buffer,256);

    write(newsockfd,"Hi I am server",18);

}
```

My Question is on other computer system I open up my Wifi and look up for available Network, I see network like 2WIRE255, 2WIRE56, HOME-1C32, ATT980, but how come I don't see my Server running from the other computer on port 3000 and IP Address of 127.0.0.12. What information I need to setup on the Server such that it will register and show up in the available network like the 2WIREs, and ATTs.

Is there something wrong with IP address of 127.0.0.12 that fails to register in the network? What IP address I should use then?

Answer (score 1):

The network `127.0.0.0` is visible only locally to a host. No address out of this network (like `127.0.0.12`) will ever be accessable from any other host but the host itsself.

Binding a socket to the address `INADDR_ANY` (that normally is `0.0.0.0`) binds it to any available interface.

Answer (score 0):

I guess may be its not listening for incoming connections on `wireless` interface. Try putting `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.12` for the `serv_addr`. This listens for connections on any interface. May be this will be helpful.